# Google Maps JS API FusionTableLayer - Get LatLng From Geocoded Location

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I've searched google every way from Sunday that I could think of but I cannot seem to find an answer to my question.

Right now I have a map that is using a FusionTableLayer to display the location of geocoded addresses. Does anyone know if it's possible to get the LatLng coordinates of the geocoded address without having to do a secondary geocoder call to geocode the address?  Or maybe get an array of all of the markers currently displayed?

like myFusionTableLayer.getMarkers() or myFusionTableLayer.getMarkerLocation(index) or something would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to retrieve the locations from geocoded addresses in FusionTables.  It used to be possible, but that capability was removed, I believe for legal reasons.

If you geocode the addresses outside of FusionTables and store the coordinates in the table, they will be available.

Comment: That's what I figured.  Do you know if there is an easy way to tell a fusion table to store the geocode information off in a new column or if I will need to write a script to loop over each row, get the geocode information, and then write it to the correct column in the row?

Comment: I have used [Pamela Fox's spreadsheet geocoder](http://blog.pamelafox.org/2008/11/geocoding-with-google-spreadsheets-and.html) to geocode addresses for use in FusionTables, it is limited in how many it can do at a time.  Otherwise (or if you wait too long), you will need to write an external program to geocode the addresses using one of Google's geocoders (assuming you will be displaying the data on a Google Maps API map, if not, that is against the terms of use and you will need to find another source of data).

Comment: As of late, I noticed fusion tables has a geocode function, couldn't you just run that and then call forth the raw geocoded KML points via Gviz.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work (anymore).  Although I'm not sure I understand your reference to "raw geocoded KML points", if you have KML points, you don't need to geocode the data, and the data will be available, it is only data that just contains "address strings" that is geocoded by the function you refer to that can't be extracted.